# Meteor 1.12.1 on deploy @babel/runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules

Tags: node.js, meteor, babeljs

I am trying to deploy a new version on meteor and get the next error:

```
/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:468hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 }).run();
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 ^hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00Error:
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00The @babel/runtime npm package could not be found in your node_moduleshewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00directory. Please run the following command to install it:
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at module (packages/babel-runtime.js:20:9)hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:258:21)hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at packages/babel-runtime.js:53:15hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at packages/babel-runtime.js:58:3hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:401:38hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:226:21hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00 at /app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:464:7hewvs
2022-10-05 15:03:02-05:00Application exited with code: 1zhssa
2022-10-05 15:03:49-05:00Application process starting, version 492zhssa
2022-10-05 15:03:53-05:00/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280zhssa
2022-10-05 15:03:53-05:00 throw(ex);
```

I tried "meteor npm install --save @babel/runtime"
I tried to use babel 7.0.0-beta.42 and 7.0.0-beta.50 and didn`t work
I updated all my packages and the same error, I have no error when I do npm install and when. I run locally everything works well, the problem is only when I deploy to Meteor
I tried to use the flag "--allow-incompatible-update" too but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

The older version of Meteor `1.12.1` (7-8 years ago!) is likely not compatible with Babel 7.

Either you update to newer Meteor (I suggest at least 2.5, better 2.7.3) or downgrade Babel to the supported version in 1.12.1. You can find the supported version in the changelog or by searching the 1.12.1 release tag:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/METEOR%401.2.1

contains babel packages in `/packages` that point to

https://github.com/meteor/babel/tree/v0.5.8

which is archived now and used at that time

```
"babel-core": "5.8.24"
```

At that time Babel did not even used the `@babel` namespace. Also, Meteor managed [their own version of babel-runtime](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/release/METEOR%401.2.1/packages/babel-runtime) at that time.

The best you can do is to update, even if there will be errors (mostly due to old packages) - in the long run it will be easier than to maintain deprecated babel versions.

Comment: Thanks!, but I alredy updated everything, even Meteor whit the 2.7.3 and I still having this problem, only at deploy in meteor, not in local

Comment: How do you build / deploy? Using Galaxy? Using MUP? Manually?

Comment: Using
METEOR_SESSION_FILE=deployment_token.json meteor deploy my-app  --settings production-settings.json in local and with Codeship that to the same on the cloud
The wear is I deploy versions that works 2 weeks ago and now it just don`t work whith all my Meteor projects

Answer (score 0):

I fixed using a different deploy command, I don`t know why but works now

```
meteor deploy -s settings.json
```